# linux tasklets - order of execution

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tasklet

At my university I am working on one project that involves some kernel programming. One part of this is loadable kernel module that registers interrupt handler for some given interrupt.

Now I have shared data structure that is used by interrupt handler and tasklets and I am wondering if I can be sure that tasklets are executed in the same order that they are scheduled or is it undefined?

For example my interrupt handler is called at time `t1` and time `t2`, each invocation executes `tasklet_schedule(&customTasklet);`. Now, can I be sure that the tasklet that was scheduled at time `t1` will be executed first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scheduled `tasklet` are stored within a list; the system read this list in *FIFO* order, so: yes `t1` is executed before `t2`.

Here [some code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/softirq.c#L432) to understand the mechanism.

**edit**

As reminded by *CL*, there is a tasklet list for each CPU; so when you shedule a tasklet, you are scheduling it on the active CPU. So tasklet are serialized on the same CPU. If you schedule `t1` un CPU1 and `t2` on CPU2 it may happen that `t2` is executed before `t1`.

Comment: … if the tasklets were scheduled on the same CPU.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, but what if the CPU has more then one thread? Is it for each physical CPU?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about this. But I think is for each physical CPU (core).